# Update column with previous record based on date

Tags: mysql

My table looks like this:

```
id_sensor | date_in | value | cons
```

I have a (almost) working Query:

```
UPDATE ow_data D,ow_data X 
SET D.cons = X.value 
WHERE D.id_sensor=14 AND X.id_sensor=D.id_sensor AND X.date_in>D.date_in
```

This works so that **cons** receives the **value** from the next record, since the records come in ascending **date_in**-order.

But what I want is to update **cons** with the value of the **previous** record instead.

But if I change to X.date_in **<** D.date_in instead, **cons** always receives the value from the **first** record, obviously because it comes first in **X**

I tried ORDER BY on X but it is not allowed it seems.

---

**UPDATE**

Turned out I solved it myself:

```
UPDATE ow_data D
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM ow_data
WHERE id_sensor=14 GROUP BY date_in ORDER BY date_in DESC) X    
ON D.date_in > X.date_in 
SET D.cons = X.value WHERE D.id_sensor=14
```

Comment: If you solved your problem, would you please post the solution as an answer and mark it as the accepted answer? (you seem to be rather new here -- that's the way how it's done here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark here because I've never had a situation where I had to do this, but can you do it this way?

```
UPDATE ow_data D 
SET D.cons = (select X.value from ow_data X where X.date_in < D.date_in and X.id_sensor = 14 order by X.date_in desc limit 1) 
WHERE D.id_sensor=14;
```

My example removes your `X.id_sensor = D.id_sensor` condition because if the id is known, you may as well just check against that.

Comment: Thx for your reply, i just figured it out on my own (se my update above).

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I solved it myself like this:

```
UPDATE ow_data D
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM ow_data
WHERE id_sensor=14 GROUP BY date_in ORDER BY date_in DESC) X    
ON D.date_in > X.date_in 
SET D.cons = X.value WHERE D.id_sensor=14
```